# DRBD Over LVM MKFS and accessing device

Tags: lvm, drbd, mkfs

I admit I am in the experimental stage at this point, but as I read the documentation, this shouldn't be a problem.  I am configuring DRBD over LVM.

As I understand the `drbd00.res` file, I should be accessing the device as `/dev/drbd00`.  But, that device does not exist. Instead, `/dev/drbd0` exists.  However, when I `mkfs -t xfs on /dev/drbd0`, the status goes to Diskless on the next boot.  My steps are as follows:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc1
vgcreate shared1 /dev/sdc1
lvcreate --name shared1 -l 100%FREE shared1
drbdadm create-md drbd00
systemctl start drbd
drbdadm primary drbd00 --force
```

(wait for sync)

```
[root@linclust1 ~]# mkfs -t xfs /dev/shared1/shared1
mkfs.xfs: cannot open /dev/shared1/shared1: Device or resource busy

[root@linclust1 ~]# mkfs -t xfs /dev/drbd0
meta-data=/dev/drbd0             isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=1310422 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0, sparse=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=5241687, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

(wait for sync)

```
[root@linclust1 ~]# cat /proc/drbd
version: 8.4.5 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 1AEFF755B8BD61B81A0AF27
 0: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:20977322 nr:0 dw:10574 dr:20970957 al:7 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

The I reboot and it goes to Diskless.

```
[root@linclust1 ~]# cat /proc/drbd
version: 8.4.5 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 1AEFF755B8BD61B81A0AF27
 0: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Secondary ds:Diskless/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:0 dr:0 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

Here is the `drbd00.res` file:

```
resource drbd00 {

        device /dev/drbd00;

        disk /dev/shared1/shared1; <=== This is an lvm device

        meta-disk internal;

        syncer {

           verify-alg sha1;

        }

        on linclust1.localdomain {

                address 192.168.31.101:7789;

        }

        on linclust2.localdomain {

                address 192.168.31.102:7789;

        }

      }
```

Comment: The logs should have some clue as to why DRBD refuses to attach to its disk. Also, confirm that /dev/shared1/shared1 is present after a reboot.

Comment: @OracleDBA Maybe you can answer your own post to mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the issue. I was trying to mount this as a file system referencing it by the lvm name, that made it go to diskless. I needed to mount it using /dev/drbd0. That works fine.